# TensorFlow: unsatisfiableError: the following specifications were found to be in conflict

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to install tensorflow in anaconda with python 2.7 in Win10, by conda installation:

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow=1.1.0
```

Then, I get the error message:

```
- python 2.7*
- tensorflow 1.1.0* -> python 3.5*
Use 'conda info <package>' to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Does the message mean I need to use python 3.5?

Answer (score 2):

[Yes.](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows)

> TensorFlow only supports version 3.5.x of Python on Windows. Note that Python 3.5.x comes with the pip3 package manager, which is the program you'll use to install TensorFlow.

There are instructions for installing TF with Anaconda on Win10 on that page.